# Docker containers - backspace etc not working

Tags: docker

I tried to enter the backspace etc .. as part of docker container prompt. They doesnt seem working.
Here it is ( whereever you see ^H^H^H^H , that is the time backspace is entered )

I know it might be the issue with stty etc .. Please suggest wrt to the container how to resolve this

```
training@training-virtualbox:~$ docker container exec -it spark-submit sh
# cat submit    ^H^H^H^H
cat: submit: No such file or directory
cat: ''$'\b\b\b\b': No such file or directory
# ^[[: not found
# cat submit.sh
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34566111/how-to-backspace-or-delete

Comment: I went though this, the process is little complicated, looking for simple alternatives

Comment: What's the application you're running in your container?  Can you provide your Dockerfile and other components of a [mcve]?  Can you interact with the container's standard API using `curl` and similar commands, rather than using an interactive shell?

Answer (score 3):

You should run `bash` instead of `sh` to use backspace and arrow keys.

```
docker container exec -it spark-submit /bin/bash
```